# why ffmpeg stopped while watermarking

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to watermark MKV video which is 8 GB size after watermarking 98% of the file it suddenly stops then I found the output is a good video but it is working till the 98$ of the video.

I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video_input.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay = 20:15,subtitles = sub.srt" video_out.mkv
```

Any explaination for that?

Comment: There may be a malformed bitstream at that point. Test with `-ss x` before `-i video_input.mkv`. Use a `x` value of 97% of the duration. So, if the video is 100 minutes, use `-ss 1:37:00`

Comment: That means the video output will be subtracted the last 3%?

Comment: is there is a way to skip this error?

Comment: First run the test command. It's just to check if the file is malformed.

Comment: It works well till the end but I missed the last 3% of the video

Comment: Run the command with the `ss` option like shown above.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I got the video with only 3% without any error
while I am reading the log, I found 
e=11919 fps= 45 q=28.0 size=  418125kB time=00:08:17.82 bitrate=6880.5kbits/s speed=1.87x

Comment: what is the problem do you think ?
No I have two files one for 97% and one 3%

Comment: Run the command for the full movie with `-report` added. A text file will be generated. Upload that to pastebin.

Comment: I did the full command with report. The good thing it finished without any errors but I can't understand what is the problem so far.

here is the log file: 
http://www.filedropper.com/ffmpeg-20160905-125647

Comment: Don't see any errors in the report.

Comment: that why I wonder why it run the same command without -report option it hangs but with it, run smoothly